# Installing minikube on windows

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to install `minikube` on Windows, but some errors appear in installation process as follows:

```
E0328 17:03:10.003001    5340 start.go:209] Error caching images:  Caching images for kubeadm: caching images: caching image C:\Users\User\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\kube-proxy_v1.14.0: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%
-   Preparing Kubernetes environment ...
X   Unable to load cached images: loading cached images: loading image C:\Users\User\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64_1.14.13: FindFirstFile C:\Users\User\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64_1.14.13: The system cannot find the path specified.
-   Pulling images required by Kubernetes v1.14.0 ...
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide how you are trying to install minikube and what else is installed on your PC. So it is hard to provide 100% accurate answer. I will try with providing a way that I use to install minikube on Windows, if that does not help please provide more information on what steps did you do that led to this error. I do not want to guess but it seems like you did not add the minikube 
binary to your PATH:

`executable file not found in %PATH%
-   Preparing Kubernetes environment ...`

First let's delete all the traces of your current installation. 
Run `minikube delete` go to C:\Users\current-user\ and delete `.kube` and `.minikube` folders.

Open Powershell and install chocolatey as explained [here](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c):

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`

After installation run `choco install minikube kubernetes-cli`.

Now depending on what hypervisor you want to use you can follow steps from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c) (Hyper-V). You can use VirtualBox as well but then you won't be able to use Docker for Windows (assuming you want to) - you can read more in one of my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600524/is-it-possible-to-run-minikube-with-virtualbox-on-windows-10-along-with-docker/52611412#52611412). Another possibility is to use Kubernetes in Docker for Windows as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) - but you won't be using minikube in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Actually, I was trying to install it through vrtualbox without using Hyper-V and powershell. However, it gave me a sort of errors. However, I will try to install it basedo n what you suggested.

Comment: if it's virtualbox and you don't need to use Docker. Then just delete traces as I explained in the answer, then install minikube and kubectl with choco and run `minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox` this should work

Answer (score 0):

1-install chocolatey:

*Click Start and type “powershell“
*Right-click Windows Powershell and choose “Run as Administrator“
*Paste the following command into Powershell and press enter.

- Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; `
  iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
  *Close and reopen an elevated PowerShell window to start using choco
  2-install minikube:

choco install kubernetes-cli

choco install minikube

minikube start

minikube status