# Unable to load cached Images in my minikube, I have windows 10 enterprise edition

Tags: image, caching, kubernetes, path, minikube

I have **tried reinstalling** it but nothing seems to work.

console output:

```
E1126 15:42:35.408904   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.16.2 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\kube-scheduler_v1.16.2 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%


   E1126 15:42:35.436232   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v1.8.1 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\gcr.io\k8s-minikube\storage-provisioner_v1.8.1 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.439164   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64:1.14.13 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64_1.14.13 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.467462   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.16.2 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\kube-proxy_v1.16.2 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.483078   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64:1.14.13 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64_1.14.13 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.485031   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/kube-addon-manager:v9.0 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\kube-addon-manager_v9.0 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.492838   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.2 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\coredns_1.6.2 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.514311   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.16.2 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\kube-controller-manager_v1.16.2 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.516262   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\pause_3.1 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.536759   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.1 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\kubernetes-dashboard-amd64_v1.10.1 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.544566   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.3.15-0 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\etcd_3.3.15-0 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.544566   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.16.2 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\kube-apiserver_v1.16.2 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

E1126 15:42:35.546525   19976 cache_images.go:80] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.13 -> C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64_1.14.13 failed: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name:  exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

* Starting existing virtualbox VM for "minikube" ...
* Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
* Found network options:
  - NO_PROXY=192.168.99.103
  - no_proxy=192.168.99.103 ! VM is unable to access k8s.gcr.io, you may need to configure a proxy or set --image-repository
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.2 on Docker '18.09.9' ...
  - env NO_PROXY=192.168.99.103
  - env NO_PROXY=192.168.99.103

E1126 15:44:39.347174   19976 start.go:799] Error caching images:  Caching images for kubeadm: caching images: caching image C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\kube-scheduler_v1.16.2: getting destination path: parsing docker archive dst ref: replace a Win drive letter to a volume name: exec: "wmic": executable file not found in %PATH%

* Unable to load cached images: loading cached images: loading image 

C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\kube-controller-manager_v1.16.2: CreateFile 

C:\Users\Sanket1.Gupta\.minikube\cache\images\k8s.gcr.io\kube-controller-manager_v1.16.2: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was raised in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403284/installing-minikube-on-windows). I am posting a community wiki answer from it:

---

You did not provide how you are trying to install minikube and what else is installed on your PC. So it is hard to provide 100% accurate answer. I will try with providing a way that I use to install minikube on Windows, if that does not help please provide more information on what steps did you do that led to this error. I do not want to guess but it seems like you did not add the minikube 
binary to your PATH:

`executable file not found in %PATH%
-   Preparing Kubernetes environment ...`

First let's delete all the traces of your current installation. 
Run `minikube delete` go to C:\Users\current-user\ and delete `.kube` and `.minikube` folders.

Open Powershell and install chocolatey as explained [here](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c):

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`

After installation run `choco install minikube kubernetes-cli`.

Now depending on what hypervisor you want to use you can follow steps from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c) (Hyper-V). You can use VirtualBox as well but then you won't be able to use Docker for Windows (assuming you want to) - you can read more in one of my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600524/is-it-possible-to-run-minikube-with-virtualbox-on-windows-10-along-with-docker/52611412#52611412). Another possibility is to use Kubernetes in Docker for Windows as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) - but you won't be using minikube in this scenario.

---

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi, I did exactly as instructed, I uninstalled and deleted everything and reinstalled minikube using chocolatey using PowerShell, but the error still persists, but during installation, there were 3 packages, in which 1 was not installed and the error was


kubenetes-cli not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.

Comment: [Here](https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting#package-not-installedthe-package-was-not-found-with-the-sources-listed) you can find a way to handle this error. And [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/kubernetes-cli) how to install kubernetes-cli.